# Fast algorithm to get $k^n \pmod{ka}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The title is a question itself.

Does exist any fast algorithm to get $$k^n \pmod{ka}$$ ?

($k, a, n > 1 $, natural number)

Comment: what has been tried ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee any suggestions would be welcomed. I checked wikipedia, but I didn't get any clues.

Comment: hint Euler's totient.

Comment: can it be applied when numbers are not coprime?

Comment: How fast do you want it? Exponentiation by squaring is requires $O(\log n)$ multiplications modulo $ka$.

Comment: @SBareS oh I've lost a very basic thing...

Comment: you can reduce the problem to $k(k^{n-1} \pmod a)\pmod{ka}$

Comment: We have $\ k^n\bmod ka\, =\, k(k^{n-1}\bmod a)\ $ by the [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242), and the latter power can be computed quickly by repeated squaring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have $k,a>n$ we would probably just have to do the exponentiation, rather than reduce the exponent using [Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)/[Carmichael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) etc. - but it might be worth checking that (although probably not for an coded system). In particular if $a$ is composite with no small factors it may not be worth the time to determine its factors, since the exponentiation calculation is not very time-consuming anyway.

Assuming that any reduced exponent has been determined, calculate $k^{n-1} \bmod a$ using [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), then multiply by $k$.

Note that you may need to handle intermediate values as large as $a^2$, if using simple multiplication.